# Find an upper bound for $ x$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

If $f_1(x)=x, f_2(x)=x^x, f_{n+1}(x)=x^{f_n(x)}$ for $x \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$.

How do you find an upper bound for $x$ as $n \to \infty$ where f_n(x) exists.

Comment: Hint: If $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ exists then $f(x) = x^{f(x)}$

Comment: I got up to x=f(x)^(1/(f(x)). Not sure how to go on.

Comment: Write it as $\frac{\log f(x)}{f(x)} = \log x$. Now try to show that the maximum of the function $g(z) = \frac{\log z}{z}$ is $e^{-1}$ so $\log x \leq e^{-1}$